# Repeat average‎

Tags: code-golf, random, statistics

### Background

It was a normal presentation that I were in as a audience, until the presenter gave a math problem about repeat taking 2 number out of a list a replacing them with average, claiming that there will be something special about it, and our math teacher, sitting at the end of classroom, exciting rushed to me, and tasked me to code that out.

### Task

2 input `length` and `generation`

1. Generate a range, start from 0, with length of `length`
2. Randomly choose 2 number (or item) `X` and `Y` and replace both `X` and `Y` with the average of `X` and `Y`
3. Repeat step 2 for `generation` times
4. Output minimum, maximum, average, and the processed list.

### Example

I'll let this semi-golfed python code explain itself :)

```
import random
a,b=map(int,input().split())
l=[*range(a)]
s=lambda:random.randint(0,a-1)
for i in range(b):
    x,y=s(),s();l[x],l[y]=[(l[x]+l[y])/2]*2
print(min(l),max(l),sum(l)/a,l)
```

### Rules

- Standard rules applies
- Input can be in any convenience form.
- As long as you output is clean, understandable, readable, it is allowed.
- The two random value `X`,`Y` should be *uniform statistically independent* random by itself(`X` and `Y` are not affecting each other no matter what)

### what you should do?

- Start golfing right now!

Comment: Technically the procedure doesn't change the average, it's always (length-1)/2, isn't it?

Comment: @Neil exactly yes, you are smart, you can also prove it with math.

Comment: Can `X` and `Y` be equal?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yes, as long as it's both random, it can have a chance to equal

Comment: "Randomly choose 2 number" - [this needs further specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909). Does it have to be a uniform random distribution? Must they be independently chosen?

Comment: Is it random with replacement or without?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
ḶJX,XƊṬ×ịÆm¥oʋƊ⁹¡µṂ;Ṁ;Æm,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qZWxsef//4bi2SlgsWMaK4bmsw5fhu4vDhm3CpW/Ki8aK4oG5wqHCteG5gjvhuYA7w4ZtLP///zEw/zU)

Outputs `[[min, max, mean], list]`. Takes `length` as the first argument, and `generation` as the second

### How it works

```
ḶJX,XƊṬ×ịÆm¥oʋƊ⁹¡µṂ;Ṁ;Æm, - Main link. Takes L on the left, G on the right
Ḷ                         - [0, 1, ..., L-1]
              Ɗ           - Previous 3 links as a monad f(R):
 J                        -   Indices of R
     Ɗ                    -   To the indices of R:
  X                       -     Randomly choose one
    X                     -     Randomly choose one again
   ,                      -     Pair; [i, j]
             ʋ            -   Last 4 links as a dyad g([i, j], R):
      Ṭ                   -     Boolean array with 1s at i and j
           ¥              -     Last 2 links as a dyad h([i, j], R):
        ị                 -       Get R[i] and R[j]
         Æm               -       Take the mean
       ×                  -     Replace the 1s with the mean
            o             -     Or; replace the elements at i and j in R with the mean
               ⁹¡         - Apply f(R) G times
                 µ        - Use this list L' as the new argument
                  Ṃ       - Minimum
                    Ṁ     - Maximum
                      Æm  - Mean
                   ; ;    - [Min, Max, Mean]
                        , - Pair with L'
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 60 bytes

Prompts for length and generation. Index origin = 0

```
v←⍳l←⎕⋄⍎∊⎕⍴⊂'v[i]←(+/v[i←(?l),?l])÷2⋄'⋄(⌊/v),(⌈/v),(+/v÷l),v
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tfxmQ@ah3cw6I6pv6qLvlUW/fo44uELt3y6OuJvWy6MxYoKSGtj6QBWLY52jq2OfEah7ebgRUrg7EGo96uvTLNHWAdAeYBqo9vB2orOw/0A6u/2lchgZcplxgytDAwIALAA)

The results in TIO are output in the order listed in the question. The second example in TIO shows that by generation=1000 all elements of the output have converged to the mean in that particular case.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 25 bytes

```
ʁ?(₅‹₍℅℅~İṁ£(n¥Ȧ)):₌₍GgṁW
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgT8o4oKF4oC54oKN4oSF4oSFfsSw4bmBwqMobsKlyKYpKTrigozigo1HZ+G5gVciLCIiLCI3XG4zIl0=)

25 bytes of fun. Takes `length` then `generations` and outputs `[list, [Max, Min], average]`. Can be [24 bytes with the `W` flag](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiyoE/KOKCheKAueKCjeKEheKEhX7EsOG5gcKjKG7CpcimKSk64oKM4oKNR2fhuYEiLCIiLCI3XG4zIl0=)

### Explained

```
ʁ?(₅‹₍℅℅~İṁ£(n¥Ȧ)):₌₍GgṁW
ʁ                          # The range [0, length) - this will be the list we modify
 ?(                        # (generation) times:
   ₅‹                      #   push the top of the stack, and its length + 1
     ₍℅℅                   #   choose two random items from the range [0, length) and place them into a list
        ~İ                 #   without popping anything, get the item at each randomly chosen index from the top list - this leaves [list, indexes, items] on the stack
          ṁ£               #   place the average of those two items into the register
            (...)          #   for each index i in the indexes list:
             n¥Ȧ           #      list[i] = register (the mean)
                 )         # close the main for loop
                  :        # now the top of the stack is the list with all the replaced items. We duplicate it so we can extract the juicy info from it
                   ₌₍Ggṁ   # Push a list of [max, min] and push the mean of that list
                        W  # Wrap everything into a single list and implicitly print
```

Comment: the length, the mighty lyxal god, you forgot about the length!(the list length your code generated is `length+1`)

Comment: @okie fixed‎‎
‎
‎

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 145 bytes

Expects `(length)(generation)`. Returns `[min, max, avg, list]`.

```javascript
with(Math)f=(n,a=[k=n],R=random)=>g=m=>k?g(m,a[--k]=k):m?g(m-1,a[i=R()*n|0]=a[j=R()*n|0]=(a[i]+a[j])/2):[min(...a),max(...a),eval(a.join`+`)/n,a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc3NDoIwEATgu0@yK6WAiReTxSfwwrVpwobfAm0NEPTgu2NNTDx4m/nmMANvvFSzua@x83Wz7w@z9nDjtceWwAkmNZLToqCZXe0tUt6RpXy8dmAFqzgeNY14sZ8eZ0EMFYBH90o1sRp@BcKko0AakxNelDUOpJSMwvLzm5qNJ2A5eOPKqMQk/Ou98m7xUyMn30ELWYqQIh7@9ZwG398)

Comment: you forgot the statics about the processed list (average,min,max)

Comment: @okie Ugh. I missed that part entirely ... :-/ Edit: now fixed.

Comment: Maybe you can simplify `eval(a.join\`+\`)/n` to `~-n/2`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 134 bytes

```
from random import*
R=randrange
def f(l,g):*a,=range(l);exec("a[x]=a[y]=a[x:=R(l)]/2+a[y:=R(l)]/2;"*g);return min(a),max(a),sum(a)/l,a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY329KK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFleQLUgAiNNTuVJS0xTSNHJ00jWttBJ1bMGCGjma1qkVqckaSonRFbG2idGVIKLCyjYIKBOrb6QNFIFzrJW00jWti1JLSovyFHIz8zQSNXVyEytAVHFpLpDSz9FJhLhmQ0FRZl6JRpqGoYGOgqGBpiZEGOZYAA)

-13 bytes thanks to pxeger using `randrange` and `:=`

Comment: your loop method looks awesome! I didn't know you could do that if you don't need iter value

Comment: @okie Ah, yeah, it's a pretty helpful tip. Anyway, if you don't need the iter value, another thing you can do is just repeat the code and `exec` it :P

Comment: [134 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY329KK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFleQLUgAiNNTuVJS0xTSNHJ00jWttBJ1bMGCGjma1qkVqckaSonRFbG2idGVIKLCyjYIKBOrb6QNFIFzrJW00jWti1JLSovyFHIz8zQSNXVyEytAVHFpLpDSz9FJhLhmQ0FRZl6JRpqGoYGOgqGBpiZEGOZYAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υιＦＥＮＥ²‽ＬυＵＭυ⎇№ιλ⊘ΣＥι§υμκＩ⟦⌊υ⌈υ⊘⊖Ｌυυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49C8IwEIb3/oqMF4iggpOT1MGClaJu4hDbaIP5KGlS6q@PlyKiNx333vPc1S13teUqxrt1BArTBX8I@iYcUEqq0LcQGJF0nU15ybv/HUbSaMnIkZvGatgL8/DI0FQpy63WGCXLWTjD3QtyG4wHyYhCfMfVIBo4BT3JcbrxhWnEmAidLIw8Kd6vnEQq572HSymN1EiE6f747T@yraid0MJ47H8eYiRc0RTjYp6t4mxQbw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ⊞υι
```

Generate a range of length `length`.

```
ＦＥＮＥ²‽Ｌυ
```

Generate `generation` pairs of random integers also in that range, and loop over those pairs.

```
ＵＭυ⎇№ιλ⊘ΣＥι§υμκ
```

Update the array at those two indices with the average of the two values that are there.

```
Ｉ⟦⌊υ⌈υ⊘⊖Ｌυυ
```

Output the minimum, maximum, average and values.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, <s>133</s> <s>131</s> 128 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(l,g):
 *r,=range(l)
 while g:shuffle(r);*r,x,y=r;r+=[(x+y)/2]*2;g-=1
 return min(r),max(r),sum(r)/l,r
```

[Try this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY49DoMgGIZ3TvGNoBh_pkbDSZoOJgKSAJpPiDr1IF1c2gv0NL1NaUzf5RneZ3ger3kP4-SP4xmDKi6fu8LJAfZ-SDBunjBkZJAKFLVcs5ZAhlykX0tqGYF1NFaCbpcxKmUlRdYlYeO7wA5zcaVbvrOyuWVNpwtRE0AZInpwxieXu377YYkuobQcz4z3jMYHqmhdcairNMbO5x_6BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 44 bytes

```
(<./;>./;];+/%#)@(2&((?#)(2%~1#.{)`[`]}])i.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWz09K3tgDjWWltfVVnTQcNITUPDXllTw0i1zlBZr1ozITohtjZWM1NP878mV2pyRr6CiUKagqEBF9d/AA)

Outputs Min / Max / List / Avg

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 87 bytes

```
[ iota >array [ randomize 2 cut* mean dup 2array append ] repeat dup minmax pick mean ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDRSsNQDH3vVxyfBkVKN98Uhi8ivkzQ@TT2ENt0DWvvveamY9vP17tOVAIhyTmc5KShyryOH@8vq@d7kCqdInbsWKmTM5l4F7FnddyhJ2unVERLSDSpIpRc7XtE/hrYVRz/qoKPphQRlM1OQcUZHrJsfluWJebluIF4Iyynpdj8KMmZsUA1WI6eyaEeAhZXCoXArsYWyoHJJqgX19MRQar9lb8dK@q6bJMEl03nE22bbg4p39US/k9N5RHADfI8x@p1/TQV61YiOnGMyrsDq0VYy/CDhcHQaPKql7eksccklSx7iM0inDcQnOxa60n5wlCmusAb9/6Q@l9taXDyA2rvZoZP7oQT3HORFZiiKMZv)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN (CBQN)](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 56 bytes

```
{A←+´÷≠,(⌈´∾⌊´∾A∾⋈){∾˜∘A⌾((2•rand.Range≠)⊸⊏)}⍟↕}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704qTBvwfpH81ekPZq_UuFR2wQFIHtpaUmarsXN9GpHoID2oS2Htz_qXKCj8ain49CWRx37HvV0gWlHELu7Q7MaSJ-e86hjhuOjnn0aGkaPGhYVJeal6AUl5qWnAnV-mDt1peajrh2Puvo1QezaR73zgfSKR21TwVyIdZuADuDiAuoNzsgvVzBScFMwhUgsWAChAQ)

fixed after ovs' comment.

-1 from ovs.

Comment: does that recompute `2•rand.Range` every iteration?

Comment: No it didn't. But `∾˜∘A` saves a byte over `(2⥊A)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 81 bytes

```julia
l\g=(L=[0.:~-l;];1:g.|>_->(r=rand(1:l,2);L[r].=sum(L[r])/2);(extrema(L),~-l/2,L))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/Pycm3VbDxzbaQM@qTjfHOtba0Cpdr8YuXtdOo8i2KDEvRcPQKkfHSNPaJ7ooVs@2uDRXA8TS1AcKaaRWlBSl5iZq@GjqADXrG@n4aGr@dyjOyC9XMDSIMeQiwDSFMs1jDA0M/gMA)

expects `length\generation` and returns `((min, max), mean, list)`

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 85 bytes

```
Prompt L,G
seq(I,I,0,L-1→A
For(I,1,G
rand(dim(ʟA→B
SortA(ʟB,ʟA
mean({ʟA(1),ʟA(2→ʟA(1
Ans→ʟA(2
End
Disp min(ʟA),max(ʟA),mean(ʟA),ʟA
```

<sup>`seq(I,I,` can be replaced with `randIntNoRep(` for -3 bytes if the calculator supports it.</sup>

Output is displayed.